# not sure how to do this

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Julie is required to pay a 2 percent tax on all income over 3,000. She also has to pay 2.5 percent on all income over 20,000. She earned more than 20,000 and paid 992.50 what was her total income

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be her total income, then we have: $0.02(x-3,000) + 0.025(x-20,000) = 992.5$ Can you solve this linear equation?

Answer (score 1):

She earns more than $20,000$

So she pays $2\%$ on her her income between $3,000$ and $20,000$, i.e. she pays $2\%$ on $17,000$ which gives:

$17,000\times2\% = 340$

Subtract that from the given total tax burden of $992.5$ to get the tax she paid for her income above $20,000$ as follows:

$992.5-340 = 652.5$

Define her total income as $x$ and her income above $20,000$ as $y$ so that:

$x = 20,000 + y$

The tax she pays on $y$ was calculated above as $625.5$ which according to the question is $2.5\%$ of $y$ (her income above $20,000$) so that:

$y\times 2.5\% = 652.5$

solving this for $y$ gives:

$y=\cfrac{652.5}{2.5\%}= \cfrac{652.5\times4}{10\%} = 6,525\times4 = 13,050\times2= 26,100.$

So $y$ (her income above $20,000$) was $26,100$ and her total income is hence:

$x= 20,000 + y =$

$20,000+26,100=$

$46,100.00$

Comment: A friendly reminder that visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) can help make your mathematics appear easier to read.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thank you, sorry my answer was difficult to read.  I made some edits (e.g. replaced the K which I had used to indicate multiples of 1,000, used the , consistently amongst others).  I visited that page, but frankly, here it didn't help much.  How would you indicate a product (I used *) and a division (I used /)?  Couldn't find that on the page.  Feel free to edit one example in my answer, then I'll see and adjust the rest accordingly!

Comment: You can also view other people's $\LaTeX$ code in their questions, answers, and comments by rightclicking and and selecting "Show Math As>TeX Commands."  We generally use \cdot $\cdot$ to denote multiplication, though there are times we prefer \times $\times$.  Division has a number of ways, but I usually use \frac{num}{den} $\frac{num}{den}$ as it generally has the fewest rendering errors.  Also, note that % and \$ signs if you wish for them to display, then add an extra \ at the beginning (appears as \% or \\$)

Comment: @ JMoravitz  Many thanks for this information, and the edits!  That's very helpful.  I copied for future reference, and adjusted further, to try it out and make some steps clearer.  Isn't there a bit of a trade off, though, between answering a question quickly,  and absolute rigourous notation?  This is probably something for a meta discussion, and I agree different notation may cause confusion.  But I think "quick and dirty" answers may at times be very helpful, if the context makes it clear what is meant, although the notation is not 100% in compliance with conventions, what do you think?

Comment: With practice it doesn't take any significant amount of time longer.  If you continue in math, everything you write for homework or projects and papers will be in TeX, so it is a good skill to develop (writing in TeX quickly and efficiently).

Answer (score 1):

I think I follow what you're asking. Your question states that for income over \$3,000, the tax rate is 2%, and that for income over \$20,000, the tax rate is 2.5%. Is that correct?

(I doubt that the question is asking you to calculate taxes on her first \$17,000 and her remaining income minus the \$17,000 separately, as most questions of this kind bear resemblance to U.S. income tax, which uses tax brackets, and in which you only pay in one bracket.)

If so, this is what the question is asking: knowing that Julie's income was more than \$20,000, how much did she make if she paid \$992.50 in taxes?

We know that Julie was taxed 2.5% of her income, but we don't know her income, so we'll call her income $x$.

Now, the way to solve this question is to solve the equation is which we multiply Julie's income, $x$, by her tax rate, 2.5%, and get a product which is her taxes paid, \$992.50.

$0.025x = 992.50$, and solve for $x$.

Does this clarify how to approach this kind of question?

Comment: 2.5% = .025 you need to shift the decimal one more to the left

Comment: I may be wrong, but as I understand the question, the answer based on 0.025x=992.5 and solving for x would be the right if the tax rate was 2.5% on all income - but here for the first 3K she doesn't have to pay any, and for 3K-20K she needs to pay only 2%.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in the decimal place. I've fixed it now. My cat spilt orange soda on my laptop recently and the key still sticks. She is lovely.

Comment: @user70160: From the wording of 'also has to pay', I see where you're coming from, but I think that this is probably a small grammatical error, since it doesn't bear resemblance to the tax system, but I could also be wrong. Hopefully, one of our approaches is the one that this student is in need of.

Comment: @ maths525 Yes, just seen your edit - valid point.  Guess it depends which country, UK for example has a system as implied in my answer.

Comment: Oh, it does? That sounds dreadfully complicated. I feel a sudden rush of sympathy for my friends overseas...

Comment: @maths525 yes, plus the rates are unfortunately a bit higher than 2.5%....